# Doubling the cube with the help of a parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, geometric-construction

Looking into the intersection of abstract algebra and geometry, it's well known that it is impossible to double the cube with ruler and compass, since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible. However, I have read that if one is given a parabola in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is indeed possible to double the cube. Out of curiosity, how is this done?

One thing I have noticed that given a parabola $y=(1/2)x^2$, then the circle centered on $(a,1)$ will meet the parabola at $2\sqrt[3]{a}$ as the x-coordinate of intersection, implying we can find $\sqrt[3]{a}$. Is it then possible to find $\sqrt[3]{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if we're given any arbitrary parabola?

Comment: Menaechmus's solution was to get the intersection of two parabolas sharing vertices, one with focal length (the length from focus to vertex) twice the other. The abscissa (or ordinate, depending on how you oriented your two parabolas in the Cartesian plane), should give a segment whose length is $\sqrt[3]{2}$ times the focal length of the parabola with shorter focal length. See for instance [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=LLEZQC74gVcC&pg=PA156).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation that you made is very close to the proof you seek.  Given a parabola, it is not hard to construct first of all its axis of symmetry, and then the focus and directrix.  In particular we can construct axes so that the parabola has equation of the shape $y=ax^2$.  We can construct $a$ since the focus is at distance $1/(4a)$ from the vertex.

Now construct the circle with center $(a^2,1/(2a))$ and passing through the origin.
This meets the parabola at point with $x$-coordinate a root of the equation
$$(x-a^2)^2 + (ax^2-1/(2a))^2=a^4 +1/(4a^2)$$
The equation simplifies to $a^2x^4 -2a^2x=0$. The roots are $0$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: There is also the solution that relies on finding the intersection of a parabola and hyperbola of appropriate dimensions...

Answer (score 1):

Note that all you need additionally to duplicate the cube beyond straightedge and compass is a compass that makes right circular cones and a "big straightedge" that makes planes--because then you can make a cone and slice a parabola off of it to use for some regular straightedge and compass work to get the cube root of 2.  It seems like those ought to have been allowable tools for a 3-dimensional construction.

It seems weird to me that it's standard to tell students that you can trisect an angle if you are allowed marks on the straightedge, but not to tell them this.

I don't know whether this is an answer, but it won't fit in a comment and it doesn't quite fit as an edit to the question.  Just call it a lamentation that teaching ignores solid geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the marked straightedge is easier to grasp, literally, as we can implement it with a standard ruler but the conical drawing tool is much harder to reproduce.

In the case of ellipses there is a workaround. We first teach the students to make ellipses with the pins and string method. Once this is familiarized, we move on to working out how to construct the foci and sum of distances of the ellipse for a given problem, so the students then know where to place the pins and how much string to measure between them. Then the solid construction is completed using the drawn ellipse.

As an example, consider doubling the cube by intersecting the conic curves

$x^2+xy+y^2=2x+y+2$ (ellipse)

$x^2+y^2=2x+y$ (circle)

Standard algebraic methods reveal that the two curves intersect at $(2,1)$ and $(\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4)$. The quartic equation for $x$ is $x^4-2x^2-2x+4=(x^3-2)(x-2)=0$.

Thereby we can develop the following solid construction procedure for doubling the cube:

1. Construct the foci of the ellipse, which are determined by algebraic techniques to be $(1\pm\sqrt2,\mp\sqrt2)$.
2. Pin the string to one of the cosine, pul it taut around a pencil or compass point at $(2,1)$ (the second root for the intersection of the ellipse and the circle), then pin to the second focus. Passing the string through $(2,1)$ in this way assures the right sum of distances for the ellipse.
3. Using the pins and string as described, draw the portion of the ellipse in the first quadrant (the rest of the ellipse has no significant points).
4. Construct the circle given above by standard Euclidean means, centering on $(1,1/2)$ and passing it through $(2,1)$.
5. A second point of intersection of the circle and the ellipse besides $(2,1)$; this point is the target point $\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[3]4)$.