# How to construct the cubed root of a number?

Tags: geometry, radicals

I am trying to use the proof in "Doubling the Cube with help of a parabola"

[Doubling the cube with the help of a parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32911/doubling-the-cube-with-the-help-of-a-parabola)

To figure out how to construct the cubed root of any number.

Any help out there?

Comment: This may be some help: http://www.unf.edu/~ddreibel/mtg3203/cube-root.pdf

Comment: Minor modification of the solution will do it. If you continue to have trouble I can do it.

Comment: Andre! I saw your construction of the cubed root of 2 in the Doubling of the Cube. It makes perfect sense to me. Can we generalize that method to construct any cubed root?

Answer (score 1):

I shall present a generalization of the method given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4707054/248217) for doubling a cube. The construction is based on conic sections rather than neusis, but it can be carried out using readily available equipment if you are familiar with the [pins and string method for constructing an ellipse](https://www.mathopenref.com/printellipse1.html). The following uses a slight modification of that method based on knowing a point through which the ellipse passes as well as the foci.

Let $a$ be any positive number. We render two conic curves, one of which is an ellipse and the other a circle:

$x^2+xy+y^2=ax+y+a$ (ellipse)

$x^2+y^2=ax+y$ (circle)

Standard algebraic methods reveal that the two curves intersect at $(a,1)$ and $(\sqrt[3]{a},\sqrt[3]{a^2})$. The quartic equation for $x$ is $x^4-ax^2-ax+a^2=(x^3-a)(x-a)=0$.

Thereby we can develop the following solid construction procedure for doubling the cube:

1. Construct the foci of the ellipse, which are determined by algebraic techniques to be

$(\dfrac{2a-1}{3}\pm(a+1)\sqrt{\dfrac29},\dfrac{2-a}{3}\mp(a+1)\sqrt{\dfrac29})$.

2. Pin the string to one of the foci just constructed, pull it taut around a pencil or compass point at $(a,1)$ (the second root for the intersection of the ellipse and the circle), then pin to the second focus. Passing the string through $(a,1)$ in this way assures the right sum of distances for the ellipse.
3. Using the pins and string as described, draw the portion of the ellipse in the first quadrant (the rest of the ellipse has no significant points).
4. Construct the circle given above by standard Euclidean means, centering on $(a/2,1/2)$ and passing it through $(a,1)$ or through the origin.
5. A second point of intersection of the circle and the ellipse besides $(a,1)$ exists; this point is the target point $(\sqrt[3]{a},\sqrt[3]{a^2})$.